# Create timer job to execute powershell script?

Tags: powershell, timer-jobs

I have created timer job and under execute method.i have added below statement to run sharepoint command.

```
runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell", out snapInError);
```

but i am receiving error wherever this code is getting executed.

> Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
>   because of the following error: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71E9BCE111E9429C\Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer
>   than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Please help my requirement is to create timer job which will run my custom powerShell script

Comment: If this is 2010, then the problem is that SP 2010 uses .Net 3.5 and the commandlet seems to use 4.0